# Não consigo mudar o formato da célula com o .setNumberFormat no google app script

Tags: google, formatação, google-sheets, planilha

Fiz a seguinte página de cadastro. Eu preciso pegar exatamente
a quantidade de zeros que eu adiciono no campo de matrícula

[image: página de cadastro]

Entretanto, quando esses dados são adicionados na planilha, só aparece um zero.

[image: dados na planilha]

Estou tentando usar o .setFormatNumber da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando mudar a formatação de toda a coluna para texto simples antes de fazer o append com
um novo dado, mas continua como formatação automática da mesmo jeito. Como faço pra mudar essa formatação?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fazendo os testes de entrada manual e referenciando o valor de uma célula para outra, o formato que influencia no registro final é o da célula onde se tem a *entrada*, então no seu caso seria ainda no formulário, e como é aceito esse valor.

#### EXEMPLO:

- `Matrícula = 0000012` -> entrada manual
- Antes do `appendRow()`: `Matrícula = 12` -> número reduzido para acesso em uma "célula temporária" (chamo assim porque não sei exatamente como funciona a transição do formulário pra planilha antes da chamada da função addStudent()
- Após o `appendRow()`: `Aluno01 || 12 || 2001-06-03`

Portanto, se na hora que você está registrando a matrícula o número está ignorando os zeros à esquerda (por estar sendo formatado como número, e não texto simples), no momento em que você fizer o `appendRow()`, você vai estar jogando o valor não formatado para uma célula formatada, que vai receber o valor já reduzido.

Enquanto isso, a formatação como texto simples para a coluna de registros da planilha pode ser feita tanto manualmente para toda a coluna, ou antes do `if()`, para não executar o comando a cada novo cadastro.